# Clear Screen Without Interrupt

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, 32-bit, irvine32

I'm writing a game using MASM,

I use ClrScr which is a procedure in Irvine32.inc

but it can't clean the whole console window

some char still remain.

My code is run under 32-bits system, so I can't use "int" instruction

I am trying to write a procedure to output black-color-space to the entire console

but it will flicker when I call that proc. and it's hard to stare at screen ..

Is there a solutions?

---

### UPDATE

Here is my code to clear the screen

```
ForceCLS  PROC
    PUSH ECX
        Translate 0,0   ;Gotoxy 0, 0
        LoopTimes 50    ;Same AS MOV ECX, 50
        SettingColor Black ;Set Font Color to Black
        NewLine:
            PUSH ECX
                LoopTimes 115
                BLANKS:
                    Write 020H
                        ; Same As MOV EAX, 020H ; CALL  WriteChar
                    Loop BLANKS
            POP  ECX
            NL ;New Line
            Loop NewLine
    POP  ECX

    Translate 0,0   ;Same As Gotoxy 0, 0
    DefaultColor    ;Set Font Color to Default
    RET
ForceCLS ENDP
```

And here are examples of the output:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a program you wrote that calls ClrScr that doesn't clear the entire screen? That sounds suspicious. Seems like there is more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: You say _I am tring to write a procedure to output black-color-space to the entire console_ show us your code that doesn't work

Comment: Try single-stepping in a debugger, so it can go slow enough to not just be a flicker...

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPetch , I put my code and a gif on my question

Comment: Off-topic: What editor are you using?

Comment: @Coodey is Sublime Text 3 http://www.sublimetext.com/3 and Facebook Material Theme https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Facebook%20Material%20Theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flickering happens because when you clear the console it becomes blank for a moment.

To prevent this flickering you need to render a scene in a buffer in memory and after that output the buffer to console. You can use [WriteConsoleOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687404.aspx) function for this.

Here is a simple example of the animation in Windows console. The most interesting part happens in the `ANIMATION` loop. `RenderScene` procedure renders the scene to the `buffer`, and `WriteConsoleOutput` function sends the content of this buffer to the console.

```
TITLE Animation example


INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE win32.inc


COLS = 80               ; number of columns
ROWS = 25               ; number of rows
CHAR_ATTRIBUTE = 0Fh    ; bright white foreground


.data
console HANDLE 0
buffer CHAR_INFO ROWS * COLS DUP(<<'-'>, CHAR_ATTRIBUTE>)
bufferSize COORD <COLS, ROWS>
bufferCoord COORD <0, 0>
region SMALL_RECT <0, 0, COLS-1, ROWS-1>

x DWORD 0               ; current position
y DWORD 2               ; of the figure
character WORD '0'      ; filled with this symbol


.code
main PROC
    INVOKE GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    mov console, eax    ; save console handle

    mov ecx, 70         ; draw 70 frames
ANIMATION:
    push ecx
    call RenderScene
    invoke WriteConsoleOutput, console, 
           ADDR buffer, bufferSize, bufferCoord, ADDR region
    INVOKE Sleep,250    ; delay between frames
    pop ecx
    loop ANIMATION

    exit
main ENDP


ClearBuffer PROC USES eax 
    xor eax, eax

BLANKS:  
    mov buffer[eax * CHAR_INFO].Char, ' '
    inc eax
    cmp eax, ROWS * COLS
    jl BLANKS

    ret       
ClearBuffer ENDP


CharToBuffer PROC USES eax edx bufx:DWORD, bufy:DWORD, char:WORD 
    mov eax, bufy
    mov edx, COLS
    mul edx
    add eax, bufx
    mov dx, char
    mov buffer[eax * CHAR_INFO].Char, dx
    ret
CharToBuffer ENDP


RenderScene PROC USES eax edx ecx
    CALL ClearBuffer

    ; render 10 by 7 rectangle
    mov edx, y
    mov ecx, 7
ONELINE:
    mov eax, x

    push ecx
    mov ecx, 10

ONECHAR:
    INVOKE CharToBuffer, eax, edx, character
    inc eax
    loop ONECHAR    ; inner loop prints characters

    inc edx
    pop ecx
    loop ONELINE    ; outer loop prints lines

    inc x           ; increment x for the next frame
    inc character   ; change fill character for the next frame

    ret
RenderScene ENDP


END main
```

This example uses some function and structures that are not included into Irvine32.inc so I added some declarations in win32.inc file:

```
CHARTYPE UNION
    UnicodeChar    WORD ?
    AsciiChar      DB ?
CHARTYPE ENDS

CHAR_INFO STRUCT
    Char          CHARTYPE <>
    Attributes    WORD ?
CHAR_INFO ENDS

WriteConsoleOutput EQU <WriteConsoleOutputA>

WriteConsoleOutput PROTO,
    hConsoleOutput:HANDLE,
    lpBuffer:PTR CHAR_INFO,
    dwBufferSize:COORD,
    dwBufferCoord:COORD,
    lpWriteRegion:PTR SMALL_RECT
```